# TeXLive 2011 and subfig

Tags: texlive, subfloats

I am a long user of TeXLive on Windows. I recently moved to TL2011 from TL2010 without any problems with the iso file from CTAN. A couple of days ago I updated the TL2011 with the latest updates on CTAN.

I find that subref does not work well with TL2011. If I have the command e.g.

```
Fig.~\subref*{fig:subfig:P2jeffcott}
```

in order to get it as Fig. 1(a) and not Fig 1a, well TL2011 complains. I get an error message:

```
No file test.aux.
<newjeffcott.eps> <newjeffcott.eps>
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.18 ...~\subref*{fig:subfig:P2jeffcott} is cool.}

?
```

Process has been terminated ...

I am putting the testfile test.tex and the figure newjeffcott.eps here:

http://petitlien.fr/myfiles

(This will expand to a GMX shared folder)

Note: I do not have any problems with with TL2010 nor TL2008 and nor with the version of TL2011 that came with the iso file on CTAN. The problem arose after I updated my whole TL2011 from CTAN three days back.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: I had the same problem with Tex Live 2012. The solution proposed by @egreg worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It hasn't to do with the **subfig** package, but rather with **caption**. I didn't check the details why this happens, but it's clearly a "fragility" problem.

```
\protect\subref*{fig:subfig:P2jeffcott}
```

will do, if the `\subref` command is used in a moving argument such as a caption. The `\protect` is not needed in normal text.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Rather strange though that I am getting this behaviour with the updated TL2011. Something must have changed in the process. 1 vote up.

Comment: I tried with TeX Live 2009 and 2010 and indeed the command works. It must be something introduced with version 3.2 of **caption**, as **subfig** is the same in TeX Live 2009, 2010 and 2011 .